# react-router | how to for render of Router if components state changes

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I have simple main.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from "./components/app";

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
    document.getElementById('appContainer')
);
```

The App component defines routes:

```
render(){
    console.log('app', this.state.current, this.state.global);
    return (
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={Template} current={this.state.current}>
                <IndexRoute component={GlobalList} global={this.state.global} />
                <Route path="current" component={CurrentList} current={this.state.current} />
                <Route path="item/:item" component={ItemDetail} />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

I use the [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) package to communicate with my Firebase database. This library doesn't allow to do `syncState` for one endpoint more than once for all application. This is a reason, why I get those data in App component and want to pass them to Routes. And this is a problem.

This `console.log` in render method is called 4 times. First two give empty data, third gives first endpoint and forth second endpoint. But Routes are not updated. I can see in Template element, that render method is called also 4 times, but every time `props.route.current` is an empty array, even if in App `this.state.current` is array with length > 0.

I would appreciate any hints how to solve this problem. if there is any other way to make it, I would love to read any good practices hints. I use newest versions of libraries, ES6 and webpack/babel to build.

Comment: re-base doesn't (currently) allow you to call syncState on more than one endpoint in  single component. You can definitely call syncState more than one time throughout your application.

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis how should I understand this: "Uncaught Error: REBASE: Endpoint (currentList) already has listener syncState"

Comment: So that's just a protection against memory leaks so you don't set multiple listeners on the same firebase endpoint. What you need to do is call removeBinding when your component unmounts to remove the listener. Then you can set it again when you need it.

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis I call removeBinding on componentWillUnmount, but both components are displayed on the same page. One is a header with summary and second one is detailed list from DB. That's why I wanted to get those data as early as possible and just pass them as props.

Comment: Make a Container component which holds both of your other components that need the data then as you mentioned. But I wouldn't do that in your root component. Just in another parent component.

Comment: It would be useful, if always both components will be shown, but detailed list is shown only if user clicks on link, normally other content is on page. In your solution I will have to read a route parameter and make condition to show or not detailed list. It doesn't look as a proper way to do this. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99719/discussion-between-kania-and-tyler-mcginnis).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is good to read all library documentation.

Thanks for @TylerMcGinnis for his patience and not using hard words :)

The solution for this problem is using bindToState method, if you want only bind changes to state, but not to post changes to Firebase. It was my case - only one component needs to sync changes, second one needs only listen to changes made by first one.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Hard words are the enemy of beginners. I'm glad I practice what I preach!